# No response data available for this request after POST requests in AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I used AJAX POST request to fill my datatable. In my php file, i have a query and store it on array and return as json. But it returns "No response data available for this request" even though the fields are the same in php and database. If I include UserName error will occur. Please help me fix this one.

I already alter my Database field name from UserName to username but still won't work.

**PHP File. (user_action.php)**

```
if ($_POST["action"] == 'fetch') {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM userslist ";
    if (isset($_POST["search"]["value"])) {
        $query .= 'WHERE UserName LIKE "%' . $_POST["search"]["value"] . '%" ';
    }
    if (isset($_POST["order"])) {
        $query .= 'ORDER BY ' . $_POST['order']['0']['column'] . ' ' . $_POST['order']['0']['dir'] . ' ';
    } else {
        $query .= 'ORDER BY id DESC ';
    }
    if ($_POST["length"] != -1) {
        $query .= 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
    }

    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    // var_dump($result);
    // exit();
    $data = array();
    $filtered_rows = $statement->rowCount();
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        // var_dump($row["window"]);
        // exit();
        $sub_array = array();
        $sub_array[] = $row["id"];
        $sub_array[] = $row['UserName'];
        $sub_array[] = $row["UserDesignation"];
        $sub_array[] = $row["UserType"];
        $sub_array[] = $row["UserDesc"];
        $sub_array[] = $row["status"];
        $sub_array[] = $row["window"];
        $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="edit_user" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm edit_user" id="' . $row["id"] . '"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</button> <button type="button" name="delete_user" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete_user" id="' . $row["id"] . '"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>';
        $data[] = $sub_array;
    }

    $output = array(
        "draw"    => intval($_POST["draw"]),
        "recordsTotal"  =>  $filtered_rows,
        "recordsFiltered" => get_total_records($connect, 'userslist'),
        "data"    => $data
    );
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

**AJAX (user.php)**

```
var dataTable = $('#user_table').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "order": [],
    "ajax": {
        url: "dal/user_action.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            action: 'fetch'
        }
        // dataType: "json",
        // error: function(result) {
        //     alert(result);
        // }0
    },
    "columnDefs": [{
        "targets": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        // "targets": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        "orderable": false,
    }, ],
});
```

**Errors:**

> DataTables warning: table id=user_table - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

and

> No response data available for this request

Comment: Whats your Json response going? show please

Comment: Did you follow the link provided (http://datatables.net/tn/1) as it gives a detailed explaination as to what the error is and possible remedies.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: Maybe you should check what `$_POST` actually contains in your PHP-code. Do a: `var_dump($_POST);`. As far as I can see, you're only posting the data `action: 'fetch'` but your PHP excepts to get much more data than that.

Comment: @ H45H this is my Json file when i used var_dump($result); exit(); after fetchAll. as you can see the UserName included in the results but if I include it in return it will cause error as i mentioned aboved.

[0]=>
  array(18) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "53"
    [0]=>
    string(2) "53"
    ["UserName"]=>
    string(19) "DENIE MAE R. MORGIA"
    [1]=>
    string(19) "DENIE MAE R. MORGIA"
....
  }

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your query is getting malformed in this case because you have not set the value of `$_POST['length']` and the following comparison evaluates to true

```
if ($_POST["length"] != -1){ ... }
```

Try setting default values first

```
$length = (isset($_POST["length"]))? $_POST["length"] : -1;
$start = (isset($_POST["start"]))? $_POST["start"] : 0;
if ($_POST["length"] > -1) {
    $query .= 'LIMIT ' . $start . ', ' . $length;
}
```